# PUT request with angular2 in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, put

I need help making a clickable list which toggles color on click.
I already know how to read data from an external site, but now I want to PUT data to that site. I've already got it to work with postman.

```
http://www.external.tld/page/{id}
name = test
color = toggle
```

So I already got JSON data like this:

```
{"id":"6","name":"test1","color":"red"},
{"id":"7","name":"test2","color":"red"}
```

This is the current html code which retrieves the data:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let data of data" [style.backgroundColor]="data?.color" (click)="PostData(data?.id)">
  {{data?.name}}
</ion-item>
```

So now I need to have a working PostData function which uses the PUT method to toggle the color between red and green and send it to a page like above.

So for example if I click on the list with id: 6, name: test1 and color: red this should be outPUTted:

```
http://www.external.tld/page/6
name = test1
color = green
```

The code I got so far which doesn't work:

```
PostData(data:any) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post('http://www.external.tld/page/'+data, JSON.stringify(data), options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

Comment: Well for one thing that's a post, not a put!

Comment: Well I am pretty sure it is a put, because the post version with postman doesn't work. And I am using laravel's update controller, which works only if it receives put.

Comment: No, I mean `this.http.post` is a post.

Comment: Oh hahaha my mistake! Thanks! I was to lazy to edit it correctly since I am trying different stuff for hours ^^

Answer (score 1):

You need to `subscribe` when you work with Observables because they are lazy:

```
PostData(data:any) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post('http://www.external.tld/page/'+data, JSON.stringify(data), options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log(res); // this should print server's response after you post data
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error); // this will print error if it occurs
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you also help me a little bit out making this work, since it's not appending the id in the link and also not sending the name and color like I want.

Comment: Could i do somrthing like: return this.http.post('http://www.external.tld/page/'+data?.id, JSON.stringify(data), options) .map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe (....); note the data?.id which works in the html. And how would I send the name and color? Because im not sure if my api can read the json data and extracts what it needs like name and color.